# how does KDL ChainDynParam and its JntToGravity actually work?

Tags: ros, kdl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!
Could anyone share some tips and tricks? I've found that gravity should be 0, 0, -2 * 9.81 and this is strange.
Another problem is that JntToGravity doesn't account for last chain link. I'm very confused with that and don't know where to look.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253866/how-does-kdl-chaindynparam-and-its-jnttogravity-actually-work?/) by [eugene.katsevman](https://answers.ros.org/users/29247/eugene.katsevman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2017-02-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-05**:
KDL is actually not written / maintained by ROS / the OSRF, but is a library that is part of the OROCOS infrastructure. I think you'll have a better chance at getting good answers over at [the KDL mailing list](http://www.orocos.org/kdl/mailinglists).

**Comment by [eugene.katsevman](https://answers.ros.org/users/29247/eugene.katsevman/) on 2017-02-05**:
thanks. In a while, could you tell me if there is a KDL alternative inside of ROS?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-06**:
For some of the minor functionality (frames, etc), perhaps `Eigen` could be an alternative. For all the other functionality (kinematics, solvers, dynamics, etc), there are probably alternatives, but I have none to recommend.

Note that KDL is very much used in ROS, just not developed / maintained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, so there is a bug in kdl_parser_py. You have to specify xyz AND rpy for link origins, otherwise they're be set to 0 both, ruining your model.

UPD: Here is the link to the pull request, which fixes the bug: https://github.com/ros/robot_model/pull/187

---

Originally posted by [eugene.katsevman](https://answers.ros.org/users/29247/eugene.katsevman/) with karma: 115 on 2017-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-04-11**:
Thanks for reporting this. Have you opened an issue on a tracker somewhere? If so, could you include a link to that issue? That would help future readers find it.

Thanks.

**Comment by [eugene.katsevman](https://answers.ros.org/users/29247/eugene.katsevman/) on 2017-04-11**:
Here is my pull request https://github.com/ros/robot_model/pull/187
The discussion has stopped for whatever reason.